# Python what is the correct timefomat for: 2018-11-13T20:20:39+00:00

Tags: python

I need to get a now() timestamp like this following: `2018-11-13T20:20:39+00:00` What is the correct format string for this?

Comment: This might be handy: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be the isoformat.

You could use

```py
import datetime as dt

# Get current time in utc
# Because the datetime object is timezone aware the +00:00 will be printed
current_time = dt.datetime.now(dt.timezone.utc)

# timespec will round the solution upto seconds
iso_string = current_time.isoformat(timespec="seconds")

print(iso_string)
```

will print `2019-11-19T19:51:46+00:00`.

Comment: Your answer gives `2019-11-19T14:42:16.918844`, which is different from the sample `2018-11-13T20:20:39+00:00`

Answer (score 1):

To get an `isoformat()` string with time zone offset (the +00:00 at the end of the string) you need to supply a `tzinfo` object when constructing the datetime. the easiest way to do this is with the `pytz` library - `pytz.timezone("UTC")` returns the tzinfo for UTC.

There's another issue though, which is that technically that string doesn't quite match default `isoformat()` output because it has no microseconds. So a full example for the output requested would be:

```
import datetime
import pytz
datetime.datetime.now(tz=pytz.timezone("UTC")).replace(microsecond=0).isoformat()
```